# Not able to navigate to a different page using django views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to go to a different page using login credentials,but for some reason Getting Template does not exist error,this is my views.py

```
def checkLogin (request):
if request.is_ajax():
    param = request.POST.get('param', None)
    param1 = request.POST.get('param1', None)
    if (param=="admin" and param1=="admin"):
        Datenow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        return render(request,'./login.html',{'Datenow': Datenow})
    else:
        Datenow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        return render(request,'../../sample.html',{'Datenow': Datenow})
return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

and this is my error, i know i'm messing p the path,but i'm not sure what the convention is in this case,tried ./ ..//  ..//../ and so on,but doesn't seem to work

```
    TemplateDoesNotExist at /sample/checkLogin/
./login.html

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample/checkLogin/
Django Version: 1.11.6
Python Executable: C:\Users\Halo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass relative paths (`../../sample.html`) to `render()` - that behaviour is undefined.

Django looks for templates in [specific directories](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#loader-types).

In the default configuration you can rely on `app_directories.Loader`, which will look for a `templates/` directory in your app. If you put your login template in `<your_app_dir>/templates/login.html`, you can then render it with:

```
render(request, 'login.html')
```

It is generally advisable to namespace your templates to avoid collisions, e.g., put it in `templates/my_app/login.html` instead.

Comment: i've put it in <myappname>/templates/<myappname>/login.html,any way to render this ??

Comment: Yes - `render(request, '<myappname>/login.html')`.

Comment: thanks that worked fine,but my page is not changing,even though it says 200 Ok ,my page is still stuck at the initial screen :|

Comment: That's a separate issue - not enough information here to know what is causing it. Presumably your have some Javascript that is taking the response and doing something with it - I would guess that is where your problem is.